# InvalidRequestError when running SQLAlchemy code

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am running sqlalchemy code in atom and getting error that I don't understand because new to web development.
Also when run from terminal, it shows same error.
code is below:

`root@KS:~/Desktop/hello_files# python database_setup.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database_setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Restaurant(Base):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 75, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 130, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 158, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._setup_inheritance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 583, in _setup_inheritance
    "table-mapped class." % cls
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class '__main__.Restaurant'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

Comment: Where is the code from `database_setup` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `__tablename__` on your `Restaurant` class. Perhaps something like `__tablename__ = 'restaurants'`